# Spring Integration ( Retry Strategy)

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-integration-dsl

I want to create a simple IntegrationFlow with Spring integration, and I am having difficulties.

I want to create an integration flow that takes messages from a queue in Rabbit Mq and posts the messages to an endpoint Rest.

The problem I am dealing with is that when a request fails, it continues to retry endlessly, how can I implement a retry strategy in this code?
For example, I want 3 retrys ,the first retry after 1 second, the second after 5 seconds and the third after 1 minute.

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(BOUTIQUE_QUEUE_NAME);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(container)) /* Get Message from RabbitMQ */
                .handle(msg ->
                {
                    String msgString = new String((byte[]) msg.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    HttpEntity<String> requestBody = new HttpEntity<String>(msgString, headers);
                    restTemplate.postForObject(ENDPOINT_LOCAL_URL, requestBody, String.class);
                    System.out.println(msgString);
                   
                })
                .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a retry interceptor to the listener container's advice chain. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#retry and https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#async-listeners

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63596805Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So63596805Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63596805Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory, RabbitTemplate template) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = factory.createListenerContainer();
        container.setQueueNames("foo");
        container.setAdviceChain(RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .maxAttempts(5)
                .backOffOptions(1000, 2.0, 10000)
                .recoverer((msg, cause) -> LOG.info("Retries exhausted for " + msg))
                .build());
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(container))
                .handle(msg -> {
                    LOG.info(msg.getPayload().toString());
                    throw new RuntimeException("test");
                })
                .get();
    }

}
```

This uses an exponential back off policy.

If you use

```
.maxAttempts(4)
.backOffOptions(1000, 5.0, 60000)
```

You will get 3 retries after 1, 5 and 25 seconds.

`1000, 8.0, 60000` will give you 1, 8 and 60 seconds.

If you must have your specs (1, 5, 60), you will need a custom BackOffPolicy.

Comment: Thank you for you answer , do you have please an example ( with code ) ? , i am having troubles understanding the implementgation without a example , how am i supposed to inject StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor in the Flow ?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thank you Gary ! , one last thing, I see that spring is akin the message after 5 retries, even if they were all failed retries. normally it should Nack , am i wrong ?

Comment: With stateless retry, the retries are all done in memory with no interaction with the broker. With stateful retry, the message would be nacked for each failure and redelivered (after the prefetched). Stateful retry needs a unique messageId property to work. There are several recoverers provided by the framework. `RepublishMessageRecoverer` sends the failed message (with diagnostics) to another queue. `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` allows the broker to send the failed message to a DLQ if so configured. The default recoverer just logs the message (like in my example).